# Ladder Optimization Problem - Seeking further support for the solution

Tags: calculus, optimization

> **Problem**: Two hallways, of widths *a* and *b* meters, meet at a right angle. What is the longest ladder (of negligible width) that can be carried around the corner horizontally?

Hi, here's my approach to this problem.

I model this as a sliding ladder against the leftmost and bottom walls (as shown). The ladder has a length $l$ meters and forms with the bottom wall an angle $\alpha$. Thus, the ladder's images on the leftmost wall and bottom wall are $y = lsin\alpha$ and $x = l cos\alpha$, respectively. $r$ (as shown) measures the segment connected by a point on the ladder and another on the leftmost wall, parallel to the bottom wall, and $a$ meters away from the bottom wall. The condition is that at any time while sliding, $r \leq b.$ Thus, the longest $r$ that occurs while $\alpha$ is changing from $0$ to $90$ degrees must be less than or equal to $b$.

Using trigonometry, $r = lcos\alpha(1-\frac{a}{lsin\alpha})$

$r_{max}$ occurs when $sin\alpha = \sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{l}}.$

Plug $r_{max}$ into the inequality, and we find that $l \leq (a^{\frac23} + b^{\frac23})^{\frac32},$ which is the solution.

However, there are some questions I have not been able to answer.

1. This argument only works if $0 < \alpha \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ ($r$ is undefined at $\alpha = 0$). How do we argue for the other angles, including $0$?
2. This argument supposes that the ladder must always touch the two walls. It feels intuitive that the ladder must be modeled this way to find the largest possible length, but could it be argued more rigorously?

Thank you!

[image]